# use a PHP variable from an included file

Tags: php

hi I avec a php file (inc.db.php) which contains my config to connect to my db.
Into this file I have something like

```
$dbh = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASS);
```

In a other file I included inc.db.php and in one function I want to use the $dbh variable.
My function is :

```
function getPassword($utilisateur) {

    $uid = addslashes( $utilisateur );
    $sql = "SELECT password FROM cc_users WHERE uid='$uid'";
    $sth = $dbh->query($sql);
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    if (count($result) == 1) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

I got an error

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: dbh in /....

How I can do to use the variale included in a external file?

Comment: Either pass the variable to the function or set the variable as global within the function.

Comment: Pass it in OR build a class and set this as a class/object var.

Comment: To use the dbh variable, it needs to be defined as global.  You're trying to use it locally both inside and outside the function.

Comment: Please don't make it global.  That's just patching bad design.

Comment: And don't use `addslashes`, use a prepared statement instead.

Comment: First forget the addslashes Second build a class, create attributes as you need, and make this function a class method. Without seeing more code and knowing what exactly this function is about (it appears to be a user authentication method) I can't say more....avoid using globals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

> Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local
>   function scope.

(...)

> In PHP global variables must be declared global inside a function if
>   they are going to be used in that function.

(...)

> A second way to access variables from the global scope is to use the
>   special PHP-defined $GLOBALS array.

You'll avoid the error changing the function to this:

```
function getPassword($utilisateur) {
    global $dbh;

    $uid = addslashes( $utilisateur );
    $sql = "SELECT password FROM cc_users WHERE uid='$uid'";
    $sth = $dbh->query($sql);
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    if (count($result) == 1) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

But the usage of [global variables is considered a bad practice](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Also, using [addslashes won't protect your query against SQL injection attacks](http://www.jansch.nl/2007/11/30/dont-use-addslashes-for-database-escapes/).

[Prepare the SQL statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) or use the [quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) method.

Comment: I converted to a prepare statement like this `$uid = $utilisateur;
 $sql = "SELECT password FROM cc_users WHERE uid =:uid";
 $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $sth->execute(array(':uid'=>$uid));

 $result = $sth->fetchAll();
  if (count($result) == 1) {
   return TRUE;
  } else {
   return FALSE;
  }` is it better in term of security?

Comment: Yes, it is better for security.
You could also return the value like this:
`return count($result) == 1` (in this case is not about security).

Comment: ok,thanks. How I can do if I want to echo the result of my function. Can I do that echo getPassword('toto');

Comment: You can do `var_dump(getPassword('toto'));` or `echo getPassword('toto') ? 'true' : 'false';`.